# Codeigniter App Returns `Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in` on live but not local

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and also to MVC approach to OOP so I am already resigned to the fact that this is a mistake I have made and not likely to be a issue outside of my own code.

I have a controller (Purchase_Order) which loads 2 Models (Product_m & Supplier_m) + others.

I have built a custom MY_Model which takes 0 params and generates a query based on the model settings (table_name, primary_key etc...).

In my local instance (Wamp) it works perfectly.  As soon as I upload to the Live web server (Linux) I get the following error;

`Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in (MY_Model.php on line 58)`.

I have another Controller (User) which loads the Model (User_m) and passes via the same MY_Model route and that works perfectly online and locally.

I can only assume I have a scope issue or something similar but I have spent the last 48hrs obsessing over fixes to no avail.

I really hope someone can spare the time to enlighten me on this subject.

MY_Model

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {    
//Vars
protected $_table_name = '';
protected $_primary_key = 'id';
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_order_by = '';
public $_rules = array();
//protected $_timestamps = FALSE;

//Constructor
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}



// GET
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE) {

    if($id != NULL){
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE){
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else{
        $method = 'result';
    }

    if(!count($this->db->ar_orderby)){
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    }

    //echo var_dump($this);
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
    //die('<pre>'.print_r($this->db, true).'</pre>');
}
```

Other Classes Removed as they were not part of the issue.

Comment: It's probably necessary to post the code of the controller and models that cause the error. If you haven't done so already you might want to copy your live database to your local to ensure that this isn't some kind of data issue.

Comment: You should post the complete error message.  The most important part is left out: the line # and filename :)

Comment: Hello @rojca thank you.  I have exported and installed the DB locally and that is working fine. I have also bypassed the MY_Model approach writing a custom method in the Product_m class which contained the query as a string and still ended up with the same issue.  I have var_dumped the product object and it seems OK but 4 hrs sleep in 2 days is not helping.

Comment: @nageeb.  Thank you.  Your quite right the error occurs in MY_Model (MY_Model.php on line 58).

Comment: check your error logs for detailed error.

Comment: and which line is `58` in your `MY_Model` ?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts line58 isnt included in your code above

Comment: Yes sorry not sure why there are no line numbers.  Line 58 is this line here: return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();

Comment: @Deepak Hi and thanks.  I have been struggling to get error logs.  The web service I am using doesnt really help in that regard as the logs is makes available are empty.  I tried to add my own with the following line of code in my root .config (# Error catching and checking
    php_flag  log_errors on
    php_value error_log  /home/path/ERRORS/PHP_errors.log) but that caused another error.  (I will try to recreate that now).

Comment: @Deepak.  Unfortunately not very helpful error as it was just a  500 Internal Server Error error.  I wish I could get access to the error logs I am sure it would help things along.

Comment: Looks like `$this->db->get($this->_table_name)` is returning null. Do you have `$db['default']['db_debug']` set to `FALSE`? It's possible you have some database connection error.

Comment: @rojoca Thanks again. $db['default'] I cannot locate that variable. $active_group is set to default?  And ['db_debug'] was set to FALSE.  I have changed this and will test now.

Comment: @rojoca Thank you so much!  Great lesson learnt with db_debug there (one I wont forget in a hurry).  It showed me that the table name I had selected did not exist but I knew it did.  What had actually happened was that the website had forced the table name to be lowercase which I had not realised until just now.  Thanks everyone for your time and assistance, lesson learnt!  Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks to all but ultimately @rojoca as the pertinent question: `Looks like $this->db->get($this->_table_name) is returning null. Do you have $db['default']['db_debug'] set to FALSE? It's possible you have some database connection error.` which led me to the answer;

I had previously exported the live DBase to a local instance to test which worked fine which naively led me to believe this was not where the problem was.

I was using a different database config setup for the live site which did have db_debug set to FALSE.  Turning it back on quickly identified that the web server/service I am using had forced the table names to lowercase.  I was completely unaware of this and I have never heard of this forcing approach before either.

Lesson learnt for me.  Thanks again for all assistance on this issue.  All credit should go to @rojoca for this answer. Thank you - time for sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, it means the codeigniter could not find a field in your database table (this has happened several times to me). 
The solution would theoretically create the fields that are missing.

To resolve this error, I use a small solution:

```
 <?php

   public function test($op)
    {
        $this->db->where('op', $op);
        $result = $this->db->get('test');
        return ($result instanceof CI_DB_mysql_result) ? $result->result() : false;
    }
```

Here we check if the variable is an instance of CI_DB_mysql_result.
This error happens because the method does not return the instance of this class!!!

Sorry, I do not speak English. :)